# Which cert should be used for `SSLCACertificateFile`?

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I run `acme.sh --issue --dns dns_cf -d *.example.com -d example.com` to apply cert from let'sencrypt.
In `/root/.acme.sh/*.example.com`, I got several files as below:

```
ca.cer                 *.example.com.conf      *.example.com.key
fullchain.cer          *.example.com.csr
*.example.com.cer  *.example.com.csr.conf
```

My server is centos 7.4 with Apache 2.4.
In apache vhost setting,I set `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` as below:

```
SSLCertificateFile "/root/.acme.sh/*.example.com/fullchain.cer"

SSLCertificateKeyFile "/root/.acme.sh/*.example.com/*.example.com.key"

SSLCACertificateFile ??
```

Which file should be used for `SSLCACertificateFile`?

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I do it.

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.2.15:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    DocumentRoot /var/www-example.com
    <directory /var/www-example.com>
        Options All
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
    </directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: you miss `SSLCACertificateFile`?

Comment: @kittygirl it is part of the `fullchain.pem` - what you are showing in your `/root/.acme.sh/` directory is the signing requests, not the certificates.  Check under `/etc/letsencrypt/live/`

Comment: confused.There's no folder `/etc/letsencrypt`

Comment: @kittygirl probably a difference in our `acme` clients. But both `certbot` and `letsencrypt` set it up this way for me.  But I don't use DNS auth, I simply stop my webserver and let it spin up its own, using the `certonly` option...

Comment: Which one should be used in `SSLCertificateChainFile`?